# Can't get Bootstrap 3's Scrollspy to work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollspy

I am trying to get Scrollspy to work, but it is not moving my page to view the items in the list. I also am using `data-toggle` instead of `href`. When I click a list item I get the firing off of it switching the active class in developer console, but the page does not move to the proper item

HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row col-sm-7" style="position:fixed; background:white">
    <div id="myScrollspy">
      <ul  class="nav navbar-nav" style="border:none">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#Java-clients-section-1">Section One</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#Java-clients-section-2">Section Two</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" data-target="#Java-clients-section-3">Section Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="informationDiv"  data-spy="scroll">
    <span id='Java-clients-section-1'>createChecking</span>
    <br />
    Some stuff la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <span id='Java-clients-section-2'>confirmChecking</span>
    <br />
    Some stuff la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <span id='Java-clients-section-3'>listChecking</span>
    <br />
    Some stuff la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
    <br />
    la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la la
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.informationDiv {
  height: 450px;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or jsbin for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your data-spy="scroll" needs to be in your < body > section.

I recently got this working on http://intern-dev.obrary.com/manufacturer.  Look at that as an example.

I did this through js, you need four things:

1 - to tag your < body > section appropriately.

```
<body class="scroll-area" data-spy="scroll">
```

2 - to tag your navbar appropriately.  Yours looks good.

3 - add the js to the head.  I don't see this in your example.  Try

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
$(".scroll-area").scrollspy({target: "#navbar-example2"}) 
});</script>
```

4 - ensure that you are accessing the bootstrap .js which includes scrollspy